# apache2 php5 combibation not working on OS X El capitan

Tags: php, macos, apache, web

I am a noob in reference to apache. I am trying to set it on El Capitan. 
1. I have enabled "LoadModule php5_module" and placed the helloWorld.php in my document root. (/Library/Webroot/Documents) (I don't need user based document root.)
2. If I run the php from the terminal then it works.
3. But it does not work when I run through the browser. It complains that I need to enable ExecCGI.
4. If I enable ExecCGI for my documentRoot then I get the error about malformed header.
5.My understanding was, I don't need to treat php scripts as CGI, if I enable php5_module and that's why I don't need ExecCGI. 
(I do have some other cgi directory which has some python scripts and they work fine.)

I also have following lines in my httpd.conf
`<IfModule php5_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
  AddHandler php5-script .php
</IfModule>`

Could some one suggest where I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the built-in apache, and I think httpd.conf is at risk of being overwritten on updates. However, in my apache install I have AddType and AddHandler reversed from the way you have it:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddType text/html .php
```

In addition, if you plan to use index.php automatically:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Finally I found the solution and it was using php-cgi instead of php. php-cgi adds the required headers which fixes the issue of malformed header.